# Maven archetype + Velocity: how to show the current directory and delete some directory

Tags: maven, velocity, archetypes

because I want use archetype to create a all in one project ,and delete some file and package by requiredProperty,
I can use Velocity show some code by #if like this:

```
#if(${mysql})
interface ${table.mapperName} : ${superMapperClass}<${entity}>
#else
```

but the file or directory can't delete

I user the code invoke the JDK method for get current date:

```
#set( $ldt = $package.getClass().forName("java.time.LocalDateTime").getMethod("now").invoke(null) )
#set( $dtf = $package.getClass().forName("java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter").getMethod("ofPattern", $package.getClass()).invoke(null, "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss") )
#set( $date = $ldt.format($dtf))
```

so I think may be can invoke file API to get current dir and remove it:

```
#set( $CurPath = $package.getClass().forName("java.nio.file.Paths").getMethod("get").invoke(".") )
#set( $CurPathStr = $CurPath.toAbsolutePath().normalize().toString() )
#set( $CurPathStrSys = $package.getClass().forName("java.lang.System").getMethod("getProperty").invoke("user.dir") )
```

but get error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:3.2.0:generate (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: Error merging velocity templates: Invocation of method 'getMethod' in  class java.lang.Class threw exception java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: java.nio.file.Paths.get() at archetype-resources/__rootArtifactId__-service/src/main/java/MainApplication.java[line 5, column 69] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Comment: Archetypes are intended to create particular templates for an project type... It sounds like you are trying to fight the archetype...

Comment: Agree with @khmarbaise, you are likely better off creating a separate template for each technology supported. Archetypes are somewhat customizable, but not intended to be infinitely so.

Comment: then there will be many type archetype,but I want use this to customize some dependency and demo code

Answer (score 0):

the error is the java reflect error,I get the right fun like this:

```
#set( $RunPath = $package.getClass().forName("java.lang.System").getMethod("getProperty",$package.getClass().forName("java.lang.String")).invoke(null,"user.dir") )
#set( $separator = $package.getClass().forName("java.io.File").getField("separator").get($package.getClass().forName("java.lang.String")))
#set( $packagePath = $package.replace(".",$separator))
#set( $CurPath = $RunPath + $separator + $parentArtifactId + $separator + $artifactId + $separator + "src" + $separator + "main" + $separator + "java" + $separator +  $packagePath + $separator  )
```

so it can delete some file by this:

```
#if(${mongo} == "false")
    #set($mongoConfig = $CurPath + "dao" + $separator + "config" + $separator  +  "MongoConfig.java")
    #set($isDelete = $package.getClass().forName("java.io.File").getMethod("delete").invoke($package.getClass().forName("java.io.File").getConstructor($package.getClass().forName("java.lang.String")).newInstance($mongoConfig)))
#end
```